# Find array objects sequences with conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Since I'm making a rummy cards game, I have three conditions to check while melding cards

1. To find a group having a pure sequence with same suit. (mandatory)
2. To find a group having a pure or impure sequence with same suit (without or with joker)
3. To find a group having a pure or impure sequence or same value cards with different suit.

Pure sequence means: 3,4,5,6
Impure sequence means: 3,4,Joker,6 (Here Joker can be considered as 5)

Let's deal with Case 1 here.

**My groups are :**

```
var arr4 = [{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"spades"}];

var arr5 = [{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":7,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":20,"suit":"joker"},{"value":8,"suit":"hearts"}];

var arr6 = [{"value":1,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"}];

var arr7 = [{"value":1,"suit":"diams"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"}];
```

Here, `arr6` is of a pure sequence since every item has same suits. `arr4` does not contain all same suits, so it isn't

**For Case 1**

I tried finding an array with pure sequence without any suits like this.

```js
    var arr1 = ["4", "1", "3", "5"];
    var arr2 = ["5", "4", "3", "6"];
    var arr3 = ["1", "5", "3", "6"];

    function inSeq(arr) {
      return arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; }) 
        .every(function(n, i, arr) {
          return i === 0 || n - arr[i - 1] === 1;
        });
    }
    
    function findArrWithSeq(arrs) {
      for(var i = 0; i < arrs.length; i++) {
        if(inSeq(arrs[i])) {
           return i;
        }
      }
      
      return null;
    }
    
    var result = [arr1, arr2, arr3].some(inSeq);
    var result1 = findArrWithSeq([arr1, arr2, arr3]);
    
    if(result){
      console.log(result);  // To get true or false
      console.log(result1); // To get the array
 

      }
```

But, I'm unable to implement this with arr4, arr5 , arr6 and arr7 where it will return true only for arr6 because of same suits.

I want to get rid of the array and proceed with the rest 3 arrays in next steps. I don't know in which way should I do it.

So, in next steps if there's some kind of loop to check all the arrays, it will not consider `arr6`.

**Note**: There's another catch in here. I have taken the value of card A (Ace) as 1. But, if there is a sequence of `J, Q, K, A -> 11, 12, 13, 1`; then also it will be considered as a right sequence since if Ace comes after `K`, then it acts as number 14, otherwise as number 1. So, `Q, K, A` is valid and `A, 2, 3` is also valid.

Comment: please split your problems into smaller parts.

Comment: @NinaScholz So should I post 3 separate questions?

Comment: i would start with the first problem. then look what happen. maybe this helps for problem 2 and 3. then ask later problem 2.

Comment: I know. But since I got stuck with 3 problems, so to not confuse others later by adding another problem, I jotted them out together, plus to give the overview of what I'm trying to do altogether.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have updated the question and only considered 1st case.

Comment: Might help if you included the definitions of "pure" and "impure" sequences, unless you only want answers from people who know rummy... It might also help if you used Stack Snippets (runnable JS scripts; use the icon that has `<>` in a page) so that one can run the code more easily.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Updated the question.

Comment: It's a bit confusing, because your snippet shows arrays of strings (which happen to have numbers in them), but then you talk about other arrays of objects, which of course need to be handled differently. I would suggest making a choice of how you want to handle the `value`s. I'd make them all numbers as they are easier to deal with when sorting. Then, pick what you want in an answer: Something that deals with the arrays of objects, or something that deals with arrays of numbers.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I changed the object strings with numbers. I want to deal with arrays of objects. However, in my snippet, I worked with arrays of srtings, just to show what I tried.

Comment: Are you always going to have 4 cards (numbers / objects) in an array?

Comment: @VivekAthalye 3 or 4. Not less, Not more.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents would be to use a single summary function to process a card array to handle all the scenarios:

```js
function getSummary(cards){
 cards.sort((c1,c2)=>c1.value-c2.value); //sort cards by their value  
  let jokerCount = 0,jokersUsed =0, res;  
  for(let i = cards.length -1; i >= 0 ; i--) //start from end to handle jokers first (note this is assuming they will also have the larger value of 20)
  {
    let {suit,value:val} = cards[i]; //destructure suit and value properties into variables
      if(suit==="joker")
       jokerCount++; //handle jokers separately
   else {
       if(res===undefined){ //first non joker card -> init values
         res = {uniqueSuit: suit, startOfSequence: val}; 
          if(jokerCount) res.jokersUsed =true;          
        }
        else {
         if(suit !== res.uniqueSuit) //check if there are more suits
          delete res.uniqueSuit; //no unique suit -> remove the property (alternative: set the prop to 'none')

          if(res.startOfSequence && --res.startOfSequence != val){ //check if the sequence is intact           
           if(val === 1 && i === 0 && res.startOfSequence ===10) //Ace
             res.startOfSequence++; //Ace is used as 14
           else {
             let gap = res.startOfSequence - val;              
              if(gap > 0 &&jokerCount >= gap){ //if enough jokers remaining, use them (sequence still intact)
                jokerCount-=gap;
                jokersUsed+=gap;
                res.startOfSequence=val;
              }
              else
                delete res.startOfSequence; //no sequence -> remove property from res
            }
          }
       }
     }
  }
  
  if(res === undefined){
     //only jokers (is this possible?) -> create sequence or matching values
     res={};
      //loop through suits or do what's needed to create best score
      return res;
  }
  
  if(res.startOfSequence) //Sequence found => all cards handled => return result
   return res;
  
  if(jokersUsed)   //jokers were used for sequence, but sequence was not complete
      jokerCount += jokersUsed; //reclaim jokers
 
  const addSameValue = (suit,val)=>{ //helper function to add cards of same value to collection
  if(!res.sameValues)res.sameValues = {};    
    res.sameValues[val] = (res.sameValues[val] | 1) +1; //offset always 1 because adding is done from prev. value
  };
  
  //search for same values
  let prev, cnt =cards.length - jokerCount;
  for(let i=0 ; i < cnt ; i++){
    let val = cards[i].value;
      if(prev == val)
       addSameValue(cards[i].suit,val);
      else
       prev = val;
  }

  if(jokerCount){
     //use for highest value or add to existing sequences?
      //for example, add to highest value: (might want to check for unused suits)
      addSameValue('joker', cards[cards.length-jokerCount].value);    
  }  
  return res;
}

var arr4 = [{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"spades"}];
var arr5 = [{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":7,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":20,"suit":"joker"},{"value":8,"suit":"hearts"}];
var arr6 = [{"value":1,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"}];
var arr7 = [{"value":1,"suit":"diams"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"}];
var arr8 = [{"value":11,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":12,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":13,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":1,"suit":"hearts"}]; 
var arr9 = [{"value":8,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":8,"suit":"diams"},{"value":9,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":9,"suit":"spades"}]; 


for(let arr of [arr4,arr5,arr6,arr7, arr8,arr9]) 
  console.log(getSummary(arr)); //test output
```

The resulting objects will contain the relevant information. If there is a sequence, the result object will contain a property `startOfSequence` which indicates that there is a sequence and holds the first value of that sequence. If there is a unique suit, it is set in the uniqueSuit property. And finally if a joker is used to create the sequence a property jokersUsed is added (to indicate impure sequences? )

*edit*
Altered the code for getting cards with the same value. If found the result will contain an object `sameValues` with properties containing the values that are found with the number of times they occur.

Comment: I didn't understand the startOfSequence here. For example, in your result, the first object shows `"startOfSequence": 2` . Just explain this part. And by `all the scenarios` you meant, Case 3 also?

Comment: if `startOfSequence` is 2, it means that there is a sequence, where the first value is 2. So the sequence is 2,3,4,5. If startOfSequence` is 6, the sequence is 6,7,8,9

Comment: Regarding case 3, it should suffice for "having a pure or impure sequence ", as in `startOfSequence ` is filled => a sequence is found, and `jokersUsed` to indicate if the sequence is impure. I've missed the ` same value cards with different suit` part in case 3. Could you explain what kind of result you expect? As in, all cards should have the same value and have a different suit, or if there are cards present with the same value, regardless of suit.

Comment: Cool. Regarding case 3: I'm expecting cards having same value but different suit (with or without joker).

Comment: This is getting a bit out of hand for a single answer :D , but here goes. The edit contains the suggestion for finding multiple cards of the same value. I'm sure there are numerous other rules and exceptions for the game, but the idea for the starting point remains the same: have a single entry point for evaluating the cards and store them in a result object.

Comment: I was trying to tweak the condition `if(suit==="joker")` to `if(suit==="joker" || val == joker)`, where the `joker` variable stores a card value which can be considered as joker also apart from normal joker. But it's not catching `jokersUsed` for the second case. Just replaced 20 in arr5 with 3 and "joker" with "diams" and kept 3 in a variable named `joker`. Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/od7g7u9c/2/ Check the link. It's printing used joker in console, but not adding joker used The result it's showing for value 20 of suit joker is different from the variable joker. O_O

Comment: To detect the jokers, the code took advantage of the greater value of the joker to sort them to the end. If a smaller value can be a joker, the sorting style would have to be changed, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/od7g7u9c/3/

Comment: Nice thinking. But there are some bugs and conditions in the code. Please try to fix it, so that I can accept your answer. Would be a great help for all. https://jsfiddle.net/od7g7u9c/4/. 1. Here, in arr4, since the values are 2,5,3,4 (which is in pure sequence already having the same suit), then we can't consider 3 as a joker here. If 3 here held a different suit or if the elements were 6,7,3,9 (6,7 and 9 having same suit), then 3 can be considered as a joker and it would make (an impure sequence).

Comment: **2**. For same value cards searching, if there are 3 same value cards then count is coming to be 4 (not 3) and for 4 same value cards, count is coming to be 6 (not 4). **3**. Joker (normal and dynamic) is not considered for same value cards. `[ 2(spades), 2(clubs), joker || 3, 2(diams)  ]`. We can consider joker as 2(hearts) here.  **4**. It would be a match, only if all the same value cards have different suits, otherwise not. Any idea how to filter that? In this fiddle arr5 shows the example.  https://jsfiddle.net/od7g7u9c/4/

Comment: Glad you can work with the provided base :) , but Stackoverflow is meant to help with specific problems, not the writing of the whole program. I'm sure there are numerous other exceptions for the game (not familliar with rummy myself). The answer was based on the first assumption that a joker was represented as a specific suit. When all rules are considered, it might be better to have a different card definition. Please post new questions for the specific problems you encounter. Thanks!

Comment: I understand. But if I have to post another question, then I have to explain all over again, which might be a bit weird seeing almost same thing in different questions. Hence asked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you to use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)?

```
var arr4 = [{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"spades"}];

var arr5 = [{"value":5,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":7,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":20,"suit":"joker"},{"value":8,"suit":"hearts"}];

var arr6 = [{"value":1,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":2,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"}];

var arr7 = [{"value":1,"suit":"diams"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":4,"suit":"hearts"},{"value":3,"suit":"hearts"}];

var arr8 = [{"value":1,"suit":"diams"},{"value":12,"suit":"diams"},{"value":11,"suit":"diams"},{"value":13,"suit":"diams"}]; // another catch condition

function inSeq(arr) { // identical to your inSeq() method
  //console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  return _.every(arr, function(n, i, arr) {
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(n) + ":" + i);
    return i === 0 || n.value - arr[i - 1].value === 1 || (arr[0].value == 1 && (n.value == 11 || n.value == 12)); // checking for 'another catch'
  });
}

function checkPureSeq(arr, suit){
  var sCards = _.where(arr, {suit: suit}); // get all the cards of specific suit
  //console.log(sCards.length);
  if(sCards.length < 3 || sCards.length != arr.length) { // if same suit cards are less than 3 or the length doesn't match the original array length return false ... meaning you don't need to check if the cards are in sequence
    return false;
  }

  sCards = _.sortBy(sCards, 'value'); // sort all the cards of same suit based on 'value'
  return inSeq(sCards);
}

function log(str){ // just a util function. I'm displaying it on screen. You can put it on console
  //console.log(str);
  $('<div>').html(str).appendTo('#output');
}

$(function(){
  var arrs = [arr4, arr5, arr6, arr7, arr8]; // array of arrays, just for ease of processing, similar to the way you had created [arr1, arr2, arr3] in your question
  var suits = ['hearts', 'diams', 'spades', 'clubs'];
  _.each(arrs, function(arr, i){ // process each array
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
    _.each(suits, function(suit){ // for each suit
    //console.log(suit);
      if(checkPureSeq(arr, suit)){ 
        log('<h4>Found pure sequence of ' + suit + ': ' + JSON.stringify(arr) + '</h4>');
      } else {
        log('Pure sequence of ' + suit + ' not found: ' + JSON.stringify(arr));
        // you may push current `arr` to another array for further processing of case 2 and case 3
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Working demo can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/FxuG5gy09dhes4ITklkS?p=preview)

Note: it only handles the first case (including 'another catch' that you have defined).

Comment: It would be great if you can explain a bit with comments. I also want to find the first occurrence of sequence so that I don't want to check other arrays. However, is there a way to do something with the returned array so that for Case 2, my code doesn't consider it anymore?

Comment: I've added comments in the code to explain the logic. If you have any specific question let me know.

Comment: `I also want to find the first occurrence of sequence so that I don't want to check other arrays.` : You can use `_.find()` and return true from inside of the `if(checkPureSeq(arr, suit))` condition.